# Posting remotely to a Facebook page but post owner showing as from page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-page

I am wondering if it is possible to post through a Facebook app to an associated page as if the post was done on the page itself. I.e. if I am logged onto Facebook and I go to a page I am admin for, then when I post it will appear with the name of the page rather than my Facebook name. I would like to replicate this behaviour but coming from an external website connecting through a Facebook app. I have made all of the connections and I am able to post ok but it is coming through as my name. I am using the Javascript API with the following to login:

```
FB.login(function(response) {//do some login processing}, 
{scope: 'publish_stream'});
```

Then I publish the message with the following after logging in and accepting the permissions:

```
FB.api('/[PAGE NAME]/feed', 'post', { message: Text to post }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occurred '+response.error.message);
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

My Facebook App has the Site URL and App Domain set correctly and I have setup the App as a Page Tab and combined that to my page.

So if anyone can let me know if it is possible and how to do it, it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about Authentication, you have a User Access Token but you need a Page Access Token to authenticate as a page.

Here is the doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/